# Insert data into table where 4 fields are the same and the fifth changes

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with this structure:

```
username varchar(35)
startdate datetime
enddate datetime
saledate datetime
packageid int
```

for each username there are 5 packages, so one username has 5 records in the table, and the only field that changes is packageid. Now I have been asked to insert for all the users (around 4200) another package in the table, so the statement should be like this:

```
insert into subscription(username,name,startdate,enddate,saledate,pkgid)
values (@username,@name,@startdate,@enddate,@saledate,41)
```

> 41 is the value of the package field

I have included this statement in a procedure, but my problem is in how to access the username field (it logically should access a distinct(username), loop this field until there are no more users left,and in each cycle execute the procedure). The id column of the table is of no help, because the packages at the beginning were not added in group (so I cannot set the id=id+5). Any idea?

Comment: So you want to take the existing unique values of 'username' and simply add new rows with 'pkgid' = 41?  If that's the case just instead of using the VALUES clause, just replace it with a SELECT DISTINCT statement from your table.

Comment: @QueueMann i have already tried, but the problem is that it only adds the data from the last row

Comment: But aren't you selecting from subscription to insert into subscription?  You just want distinct usernames.

Comment: when i try with insert select, it inserts the row  5 times

Comment: Remove the columns in your SELECT list to something else like GETDATE() or to a variable like in your initial post.  Tweak it until you get no more duplicates.

Comment: The comment about looping leads me to think you may have come to db development from a programming background. Do you have the ability to redesign this table.  If the only thing changing is the pkgid, then it seems like it might help to look into normal forms and add at least one other table.

Comment: @Thronk you are right about programming background. Redesigning the table or database is out of question (It was the first thing i asked to my boss).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No loops are needed in this (**please!**).

You should be doing an `INSERT...SELECT`.

Always run the `SELECT` part of the statement on it's own first, to make sure it is only selecting what you expect to be inserted.

```
INSERT INTO subscription(username,name,startdate,enddate,saledate,pkgid)
SELECT DISTINCT
  username,
  name,
  startdate,
  enddate,
  saledate,
  41
FROM subscription;
```

If there is a specific `startdate` and `enddate` you want to use for all users, then you'll need to set them as variables.

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME;
DECLARE @enddate DATETIME;

SET @startdate = '2015-05-21 10:00:00.000';
SET @enddate = '2015-06-21 00:00:00.000';

INSERT INTO subscription(username,name,startdate,enddate,saledate,pkgid)
SELECT DISTINCT
   username,
   name,
   @startdate,
   @enddate,
   NULL,
   41
FROM subscription;
```

Comment: @name is another varchar(35) field. the select is taken from the same table where i have to insert data. And something: Why i SHOULD NOT use loops?

Comment: SQL tends to work best as a set-based language. Executing one statement for 4200 rows is higly likely to be more efficient than executing 4200 statements for one row

Comment: when i try with insert select, it inserts the row 5 times

Comment: That might be because the other columns outside of username may not be DISTINCT enough to generate one row per username.  So you might have to replace the other columns in the SELECT list to constants.

Comment: I assume that's because all the user's other rows have different `startdate/enddate` values? You haven't defined what you want them as...

Comment: If the only thing that changes is indeed `username` and all other values (`name,startdate,enddate,saledate`) are the same for rows with same `username`, then this query by Mark will work fine. If they aren't the same, then it depends what values you want to put in the new rows, for package 41.

Comment: @ypercube i understood where is the problem... in 37000 rows, there are times where startdate and enddate are different for the same user. I am trying with
`INSERT INTO subscription(username,name,startdate,enddate,saledate,pkgid)
SELECT DISTINCT
  username,
 max(name),
 max(startdate),
  max(enddate),
  max(saledate),
  41
 
FROM subscription
 group by username`

Comment: You don't need the `distinct` in this case., you are using `group by`. If you are happy with the values inserted (startdate, enddate), your query will work ok, inserting one row only per username. The values though (name, enddate, startdate, saledate) may not make much sense, being gathered from different rows.

Comment: @ypercube  the name value (Thankfully!!!) is never changing, so in the max(name) it stays the same. since i only wanted one row per username, I will take only the max values of startdate and enddate for each username

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of Mark, I was able to define the exact query as it follows:

```
INSERT INTO subscription(username,name,startdate,enddate,saledate,pkgid)
SELECT
 username,
max(name),
max(startdate),
max(enddate),
max(saledate),
41

FROM subscription
group by username
```